# Python top ten list

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
list = ('Bob', 11, 333, 453.3, 'Ted', 15, 999, 345.5, 'Jeff', 22, 122, 434.7)
```

Hi, I'am trying to build a top 10 list from the above information.

The first value  : goals, 
the second value : assists
the third value  : time played

I would like to be able to find the user with the highest goals total
in this case I would like to get a result of:

1)Jeff: 22 
2)Ted : 15
3)Bob : 11

Comment: Use a different data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a dict here:

```
>>> lis = ('Bob', 11, 333, 453.3, 'Ted', 15, 999, 345.5, 'Jeff', 22, 122, 434.7)
>>> dic = { lis[i]: list(lis[i+1:i+4]) for i in xrange(0,len(lis),4)}
>>> dic
{'Bob':  [11, 333, 453.3],
 'Ted':  [15, 999, 345.5],
 'Jeff': [22, 122, 434.7]}

>>> sorted(dic,key = dic.get,reverse = True)
['Jeff', 'Ted', 'Bob']

# To get keys as well as values use dict.items()
>>> for k,v in sorted(dic.items(), key =lambda x:x[1] , reverse = True):
    print k,v[0]
...     
Jeff 22
Ted 15
Bob 11
```

Comment: A dict is definitely the way to go, but I'm not sure if I'd use tuples, unless the scores never really change

Comment: Thanks you guys are brilliant. @ Ashwini Chaudhary  & PurityLake

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> data = ('Bob', 11, 333, 453.3, 'Ted', 15, 999, 345.5, 'Jeff', 22, 122, 434.7)
>>> for x in sorted(zip(*[iter(data)]*4), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
        print x[0], x[1]


Jeff 22
Ted 15
Bob 11
```